# Excel cell color based formating

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I am not sure if this is even possible. I have the worksheet (sheet1) as shown below.
Green - Indicates user should have access
Red - Indicates user should not have access

Based on the color coding for Member A, Member B in row 1 & 2. When Member A or B is selected in A4 to A100, the cells ("Field 1", "Field 2"....) should be enabled disabled based on the color coding. 
Please let me know if this is possible.

[image]

Comment: Yes? It is possible, now show some effort in figuring it out

Answer (score 0):

I did conditional formatting for the above and it works for me. Although it does not make the cell read-only. I have put some fill-in the cell, that makes it impossible to see whatever the user types!! :)